# Can't run command 'rails server'!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a test application, installed bundle and all the gems.
When i cd into the app and enter the command 'rails s' or 'rails server', this is what I get back:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 in PATH, mode 040777
gem install minitest
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- minitest/unit (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/railsTestApp1/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

I have tried to figure out what is missing. Desperately, I tried installing the gem minitest into /Ruby/Gems/ as well as in /Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/, but obviously I have no idea what I'm doing here. So please, I what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Can you please post the Gemfile.

Comment: Try googling your error first http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/79565

Comment: How do you mean post the Gemfle? Can you explain what information you are looking for, why you are interested in a gemfile here? Sorry, I just switched to this world from PHP and I'm very confused, I'm sure the are many out there who will read this and feel the same way. Please excuse me.

Comment: @injekt: I did. I didn't find my answer. Now I'm here. Do you want to help?